# Toggle visibility of Photoshop group on the fly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, tutorial, grids, website-templates

While watching **[PSD to WordPress Minimal Portfolio Theme](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/document-setup-color-scheme-typography-and-primary-button-styles/)** in **Tuts+**, i notified that the author toggle the first group of layers `GRID` on the fly in order to move some elements, i jest see this group of layers toggle on/off without clicking in the `eye`.

Is there a shortcode for that or it's a special plugin?
Watch the link above and see what i seen!

Comment: [Didn't watch the video] Are you certain there's not simply a Layer Comp in place. You can use shortcuts to switch between layer comps or history snapshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mailed the tutorial author **Adi Purdila** for that and he said that this was an action in Photoshop, and he also gives me his article to find more useful tools: "[Quick Tip: Speed Up Your Workflow With Photoshop Actions](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-speed-up-your-workflow-with-photoshop-actions/?search_index=1)"